# Google Chrome: How to find out the name of Transition from its id in History sql-lite db

Tags: sqlite, google-chrome

I am reading Google Chrome History from its Sql-Lite Db.

Table Name: Visits
Structure:

```
+-----+------------------+-----------+-----+--------+-----+
| "0" | "id"             | "INTEGER" | "0" | "NULL" | "1" |
| "1" | "url"            | "INTEGER" | "1" | "NULL" | "0" |
| "2" | "visit_time"     | "INTEGER" | "1" | "NULL" | "0" |
| "3" | "from_visit"     | "INTEGER" | "0" | "NULL" | "0" |
| "4" | "transition"     | "INTEGER" | "1" | "0"    | "0" |
| "5" | "segment_id"     | "INTEGER" | "0" | "NULL" | "0" |
| "6" | "visit_duration" | "INTEGER" | "1" | "0"    | "0" |
+-----+------------------+-----------+-----+--------+-----+
```

I was trying to find out what does transition means then I found the link : [Page Transitions](http://kb.digital-detective.net/display/BF/Page+Transitions) and according to it `Google Chrome stores a transition value which identifies the type of transition between pages.  These are stored in the history database to separate visits, and are reported by the renderer for page navigations.`

There are many types of transitions like `LINK`, `TYPED` etc...

In sql lite table `Google Chrome` integer values.

[image]

**Problem**

How to figure out the Transition from the integer value??

There are some more tables in the DB but none of them contains any table representing the meaning of these values.

Other tables are:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Probably a little late, but I'll just leave this here for someone else.

Here is the relevant code from Chromium source -

https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/cfe5bf0b51b1f6b9fe239c2a3c2f2364da9967d7/content/public/common/page_transition_types.cc

Basic idea is that you take the integer value from the database and convert to hex. 
Perform a **Logical AND** operation on it and convert the result back to integer. 
Run it through a switch case and get the string value back.

For Eg : In Javascript you can do the following.

```
>> "822083585".toString(16) & 0xff 
 1
>> "1610612736".toString(16) & 0xff 
0
```

Answer (score 1):

based on @jayarma S answer and on https://github.com/adobe/chromium/blob/cfe5bf0b51b1f6b9fe239c2a3c2f2364da9967d7/content/public/common/page_transition_types.h

You can map the Transition Types as follows:

- LINK              = 0
- TYPED             = 1
- AUTO_BOOKMARK     = 2
- AUTO_SUBFRAME     = 3
- MANUAL_SUBFRAME   = 4
- GENERATED         = 5
- START_PAGE        = 6
- FORM_SUBMIT       = 7
- RELOAD            = 8
- KEYWORD           = 9
- KEYWORD_GENERATED = 10

You can get these core transition type values by applying the core mask: 0xFF

There are also qualifiers that can also define the transition:

- FORWARD_BACK     = 0x01000000
- FROM_ADDRESS_BAR = 0x02000000
- HOME_PAGE        = 0x04000000
- CHAIN_START      = 0x10000000
- CHAIN_END        = 0x20000000
- CLIENT_REDIRECT  = 0x40000000
- SERVER_REDIRECT  = 0x80000000
- IS_REDIRECT_MASK = 0xC0000000

You can get these qualifier transition type values by applying the qualifier mask: 0xFFFFFF00

Here is an SQLite query to get the transition types:

```sql
select u1.title as to_url_title,
       u1.url   as to_url,
       CASE vs.transition & 0xff
           WHEN 0
               THEN 'LINK'
           WHEN 1
               THEN 'TYPED'
           WHEN 2
               THEN 'AUTO_BOOKMARK'
           WHEN 3
               THEN 'AUTO_SUBFRAME'
           WHEN 4
               THEN 'MANUAL_SUBFRAME'
           WHEN 5
               THEN 'GENERATED'
           WHEN 6
               THEN 'START_PAGE'
           WHEN 7
               THEN 'FORM_SUBMIT'
           WHEN 8
               THEN 'RELOAD'
           WHEN 9
               THEN 'KEYWORD'
           WHEN 10
               THEN 'KEYWORD_GENERATED'
           ELSE NULL
           END     core_transition_type,
       CASE vs.transition & 0xFFFFFF00
           WHEN 0x01000000
               THEN 'FORWARD_BACK'
           WHEN 0x02000000
               THEN 'FROM_ADDRESS_BAR'
           WHEN 0x04000000
               THEN 'HOME_PAGE'
           WHEN 0x10000000
               THEN 'CHAIN_START'
           WHEN 0x20000000
               THEN 'CHAIN_END'
           WHEN 0x40000000
               THEN 'CLIENT_REDIRECT'
           WHEN 0x80000000
               THEN 'SERVER_REDIRECT'
           WHEN 0xC0000000
               THEN 'IS_REDIRECT_MASK'
           ELSE NULL
           END qualifier_transition_type
from visits as vs
         join urls u1 on u1.id = vs.url
order by vs.visit_time DESC;
```

Comment: New location: https://github.com/chromium/chromium/blob/main/ui/base/page_transition_types.h